# Step up transformer for low frequency AC with DC offset

Tags: amplifier, transformer, converter

What is the best way to step-up a low frequency voltage with a DC offset?

I have the following signal coming from a function generator:

\begin{equation}
V_f(t)=8  Sin(2\pi f t+\phi) + 4 
\end{equation}

Where:

$$(5 \leq f \leq 100) Hz$$

The desired output is:

\begin{equation}
V_f(t)=80  Sin(2\pi f t+\phi) + 40
\end{equation}

Comment: how much current will you need at the output?

Comment: Are the units in volts?  How about a high voltage opamp with a gain of ten?  (Do they make transformers that work at 5 Hz?)

Comment: Hi sbell - the current may be as high as 10 amps.

Comment: 10 Amps!  That is some function generator that you have.  (It would need ~100 Amps of output current.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EE definition for a transformer is: -

> "A transformer couples two or more AC signals through a magnetic
>   field. Often used as galvanic isolation and to transform one AC
>   voltage to another".

This means it won't step up the DC content of your signal. You'll need an amplifier and a power supply.

The desired output is: Vf(t)=80Sin(2πft+ϕ)+40

The peak-to peak output is 160 volts then add another 40 volts on top of that to accommodate the DC offset. It's going to be a specialist bit of design and nothing really easily found off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply the DC offset separately from the AC signal? If so, you could use a transformer to step up the AC signal to the desired level and then add the DC offset to it.